# Using ext-direct with SailsJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, extjs, sails.js, ext-direct

I am using SailJS for one of my projects. In the front end I am using ExtJS framework. I would like to use ext-direct with my application.

I referred the post [sailsjs + ext-direct (sencha extjs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519858/sailsjs-ext-direct-sencha-extjs) to make ext-direct work with SailJS. Anyway with this I cannot make use of SailsJS features like policy's, blueprint API etc with ext-direct.

Is there anyway I can use ext-direct with SailsJS without loosing any features of SailsJS framework, or is it better to use ExpressJS itself instead of using SailsJS with ext-direct?